# Trouble with Protected and Private access modifier

Tags: c#

guys,thanks for your time.
As we known,the key words 'Private' and 'Protected' are very useful to keep some methods,fields,properties from invalid accessing outside the class.But I had got a problem in a specific circumstance.Here is the example:

```
Class Node
{
  public string Name {get; private set;}//Private setting authority
  public int ID {get;set}

  public Node Previous {get;set;}
  public Node Next {get;set;}

  public void Test()
  {
     this.Name='Valid';
     this.Next.Name='Invalid';//Is this valid??
  }
}
```

Just like the code above,we got a 'Node' Class here with two properties named 'Previous' and 'Next' which are also 'Node' type.Now let's focus on the 'Test()' method.It's valid to Set 'this.Name',but is that weird to set 'this.Next.Name'?Unfortunately,the complier treats this as a valid format！

So far as I was taught,'Private' means it can not be used outside the class.But in this situation,I can access to any non-public members( private/protected etc..) of 'Previous' and 'Next'.

This really confuses me a lot，would u plz give some advices,thanks!

Comment: You're wondering why you can access another _instance_'s setter? Your code is in the same class, i.e.: `Node`.

Comment: See also [Why are private fields private to the type, not the instance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983553/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Test()` method is a member of the `Node` class, so it has access to `private` members; which means it can set the `Name` property. It doesn't matter that it's another *instance* of the class -- it's still the same class.

A method in a different class does not have access to the `private` members of the `Node` class, so it can get the `Name` property, but not set it.

Example:

```
class Node
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Node Previous { get; set; }
    public Node Next { get; set; }

    public void Test()
    {
        this.Name = "Valid";

        // Works
        this.Next.Name = "Invalid";
    }
}

class Other
{
    public void Test()
    {
        Node node = new Node();

        // Doesn't Work
        node.Name = "Invalid";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!So the instance or not doesn't matter.The truth is the private property is modified in the definition scope.Is that right?But is that a good idea or right way to modify some other instance's private property even it's in the same type?

Answer (score 0):

It's valid, but you have to make sure Next is defined

```
public void Test()
{
     this.Next = new Node();
     this.Name="Valid";
     this.Next.Name="Invalid";//Is this valid??

}
```

It's accessible since you're inside the Node class, so private is in scope. Basically, a Node is a Node

Comment: Thanks!As u said,"a Node is a Node"!But it's so weird to do so even it's valid.Just like an overtone which break down the whole harmony!

Answer (score 0):

From the C# manual

> **private** The type or member can be accessed only by code in the same class or struct.

You are confusing this with *scope* access and not *namespace* access.. Private does not mean the member is localized by object instance. It means it is localized by defining namespace.

It does not matter if that class is instantiated or not. For example; you can access private static members.

So your code is valid, because you are accessing `this.Next.Name` from the *same* namespace. Which `this` has *private* access to.

Comment: Thanks for answering!Usually,I regard this Access Key Words as some instance things! So it make me feel so weird to modify some other instance's private property even the instance is in the same type.Although it's valid, but is that a good idea to do so like the example above?