# Why is this private member accessible?

Tags: c#

I have this class:

```
class C
{
    private String msg;

    public void F(C obj, String arg)
    {
        obj.msg = arg; // this is strange, the msg shouldn't be accessible here.
    }

    public void Output()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(msg);
    }
}
```

The test code is:

```
C obj1 = new C();
C obj2 = new C();
obj1.F(obj2, "from obj1");
obj2.Output();
```

The Output is:

```
from obj1
```

So, obj2's private member is accessed from another object obj1. I think this is kind of strange.

### ADD

Here is an useful link mentioned by Habib:

[Why are private fields private to the type, not the instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983553/why-are-private-fields-private-to-the-type-not-the-instance)

Comment: Nice isn't it? I use that a lot in my "equals" method overriding in Java.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are private fields private to the type, not the instance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983553/why-are-private-fields-private-to-the-type-not-the-instance)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> // this is strange, the msg shouldn't be accessible here.

[`private`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/st6sy9xe.aspx) members are accessible inside the class, they are **not accessible outside** the class.

[Private - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/st6sy9xe.aspx)

> The private keyword is a member access modifier. Private access is the
>   least permissive access level. Private members are **accessible only
>   within the body of the class or the struct** in which they are
>   declared

For your other question:

> So, obj2's private member is accessed from another object obj1. I
>   think this is kind of strange.

You are passing address of `obj2` to an instance method of `obj1`, and then accessing `obj2`'s private member `msg` in the method and changing its value. **But since both of them are of same type, you get the impression that you are accessing other class private member.**

Try it with two different classes and you will be able to understand it better.

Consider if you have another class defined as:

```
class B
{
    public void SomeMethod(C obj, string arg)
    {
        obj.msg = arg; // that is an error. 
    }
}
```

now you can't access private member `msg` since you are trying to access it outside of the class, in your example, you are accessing the class member **inside** the class.

There could be an argument that why C# allows `instance.PrivateMember` inside the class, the language designers could have restricted the usage of private to `this.PrivateMember`, so that the private member is only accessible with the current instance. If that would have been the case then your code would raise the error on `obj.msg = arg;`. Apparently the C# designers chosen the private to instance access instead of private to current instance only, so the basic rule is that `private` members are accessible inside the class, whether with the `this` *(current instance)* or with an instance of same type. For more discussion why this was done, you can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983553/why-are-private-fields-private-to-the-type-not-the-instance)

Comment: I think I need to understand it *literally*.

Comment: the Output method you are calling with obj2.Output() can access the msg variable but you could not access it from the outside with obj2.msg

Comment: Yes, but I don't feel you have addressed what he is calling strange. In the `F` method there is passed a local object of type `C`, this object instance is _only_ available here because the method is in inside the class `C` itself...

Comment: @Killercam, I added that just before or with your comment in my answer.

Comment: @smwikipedia, I believe the confusion is because of two objects but of same type, I have added some extra details, I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix, there is no friend class in C#, There is an [access specifier closer to friend](http://stackoverflow.com/a/204744/961113)

Comment: ahh I didn't see the C# tag

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I add your last link to my question, too.

Answer (score 13):

If i understand private correctly, it means access only from within the same class, but not only from the same *instance* of that class.

Answer (score 9):

Private means it can be accessed from methods of same class, not that you have to access it through `this`. It might seem weird, but it is still same class, even though it is different variable and not `this`.

Same thing can be done with static methods.

Answer (score 3):

The `private` modifier means that it may only be accessed within the same class - not only the same instance.

> The private keyword is a member access modifier. Private access is the least permissive access level. **Private members are accessible only within the body of the class or the struct in which they are declared.**
>
> <sub>From the [C# Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/st6sy9xe.aspx)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Similar and  weirder considering **Protected** access modifier,

```
class Base
{
    protected String msg;

    public void Mtd1(Base baseObj)
    {
        baseObj.msg = "can access"; 
    }
}

class Child : Base
{
    public void Mtd2(Base baseObj, Child childObj)
    {
        baseObj.msg = "can not access"; //compile time error
        childObj.msg = "can access";
    }
}
```